# ./configure error intalling classpath

Tags: java, linux, classpath

i am trying to install classpath on Linux(tiny core 4.0.2) but when i typing ./configure show this

configure: error: GTK+ peers requested but no X library available

How can i fix it?

Comment: What gives `configure --help`? You need to disable GTK+ peers or install X.

Comment: Thanks by suggestion if you write as response i will accepts

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're need to use

```
./configure --disable-gtk-peer
```

I had the same error as you and the above allowed configure to progress further, but it was then hampered by other errors so I cannot confirm that it works.

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable GTK+ peers or install X.